# How can I have two vertical header in a QTreeview?

Tags: qt, header, qtreeview

I want the top header to span on 2 or 3 bottom header column.
Is there a way to do so in Qt c++?

I'm looking for an exemple.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

make row1 and row2 header. and change their color to fit the header.
ugly, but works.